# how to use Application.OnKey by C# without involving VBA code?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-2007, vba

I want to use the UDF in excel template(.xlt) I have used `Application.OnKey("^v","MyFunction");`i want to use separate function when user paste the the cell in excel i.e. MyFuction but when i defined function with in the thisworkbook.cs i wont work...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. You need to define the function in VBA and call you .NET method from that VBA function, like explained here at the end: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163373.aspx