# How to activate Application.OnKey method even under protection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

I have used an Excel viewer in my C# Winform application. This viewer opens different .xls files with various number of sheets dynamically. I have to protect all sheets at the beginning of the application and also end of the sheetchange event handler.

Now I want to allow user to use some shortcut keys like {F1} or Ctrl+S. But none of the keys are working and I think this is because of the protection that I have applied on sheets. Am I right?

**Edit :**
I need to run my custom methods instead of excel default methods when these keys are pressed.So i used

```
Application.OnKey("{F1}", "MyCustomMethod")
```

in Form_Load event handler,But nothing happen when {F1} button presses on a excel sheet.

Comment: What does this have to do with `OnKey` that you mention in the title?

Comment: please see the question again,I edited it.Excuse me because my uncomplete question.

Comment: Does this question help? [how to use Application.OnKey...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5040271/976080)

Comment: @SidHolland,No because the problem is that sheets could not detect key pressing due to the protection that i have to apply on them.Infact i need a way to stop protection when the user press some of keys.